# How do I store a state object to async storage in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, object, react-hooks

I'm building a running app in React Native and I want to be able to track daily miles throughout the week. How can I save each day's milage to local storage when state is an object? The miles are entered in a TextInput and I want to submit them with an onPress in the TouchableOpacity. Also how would I retrieve the day's milage from async storage?

```
    const [miles, setMiles] = useState({

    monday: 0,
    tuesday: 0,
    wednesday: 0,
    thursday: 0,
    friday: 0,
    saturday: 0,
    sunday: 0,

});

<View style={styles.weekDayContainer}>
            <View style={styles.milesInput}>
                <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>Monday</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.weekDayInput}
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="enter miles"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    value={miles.monday}
                    onChangeText={(value) => handleChange('monday',value)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.milesInput}>
                <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>Tuesday</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.weekDayInput}
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="enter miles"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    value={miles.tuesday}
                    onChangeText={(value) => handleChange('tuesday', value)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.milesInput}>
                <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>Wednesday</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.weekDayInput}
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="enter miles"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    value={miles.wednesday}
                    onChangeText={(value) => handleChange('wednesday', value)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.milesInput}>
                <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>Thursday</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.weekDayInput}
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="enter miles"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    value={miles.thursday}
                    onChangeText={(value) => handleChange('thursday', value)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.milesInput}>
                <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>Friday</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.weekDayInput}
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="enter miles"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    value={miles.friday}
                    onChangeText={(value) => handleChange('friday', value)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.milesInput}>
                <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>Saturday</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.weekDayInput}
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="enter miles"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    value={miles.saturday}
                    onChangeText={(value) => handleChange('saturday', value)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.milesInput}>
                <Text style={styles.weekDayText}>Sunday</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.weekDayInput}
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="enter miles"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    value={miles.sunday}
                    onChangeText={(value) => handleChange('sunday', value)}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify/JSON.parse` to set/get objects to/from storage.

> Async Storage can only store string data, so in order to store object data you need to serialize it first. For data that can be serialized to JSON you can use JSON.stringify() when saving the data and JSON.parse() when loading the data.

```
getObject = async (key) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null
  } catch(e) {
    // read error
  }
}

setObject = async (key, value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, jsonValue)
  } catch(e) {
    // save error
  }
}
```

See [Usage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand I need to serialize the data but what I don't get is how to write the functions to store and retrieve the object. Do I need to use multiSet and multiGet? Also does the whole object need to be updated in storage or can a single day be updated as the miles are entered?

Comment: I decided to make each weekday an individual state. This solved my problem as I can store each day individually to async storage